# Java AffineTransform working differently on different systems

Tags: java, affinetransform

I have started using `AffineTransform` to rotate text I'm drawing with `Graphics2D` and I noticed it would sometimes work fine and other times it wouldn't when I just realized that it works always as expected on my Windows 7 PC but never on my Windows 10 laptop.

I use Java 15.0.1 on both systems.

Here is a small test case to show you my point:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;

public class AffineTransformTest extends JPanel {
    
    private static final int SIZE = 40;
    
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        int centerX = getWidth()/2;
        int centerY = getHeight()/2;
        
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.drawRect(centerX - SIZE/2, centerY - SIZE/2, SIZE, SIZE);
        
        AffineTransform at = g2.getTransform();
        at.setToRotation(Math.toRadians(45),centerX, centerY);
        g2.setTransform(at);
        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2.drawRect(centerX - SIZE/2, centerY - SIZE/2, SIZE, SIZE);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        AffineTransformTest test = new AffineTransformTest();
        frame.setContentPane(test);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300,300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The black rectangle is a regular one centered in the middle of the `JPanel`.
The red rectangle is drawn after a 45° rotation and is supposed to share the same center as the black one (as shown on the first picture).

My laptop however produces the result shown on the second picture.

[Expected result - Windows 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnZaB.png) |
[Incorrect result - Windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oht3u.png)

How can this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely because you are violating the contract of the paintComponent() method, where the Javadoc states

> If you override this in a subclass you should not make permanent
> changes to the passed in Graphics. For example, you should not alter
> the clip Rectangle or modify the transform. If you need to do these
> operations you may find it easier to create a new Graphics from the
> passed in Graphics and manipulate it.

So maybe subtle differences between the Windows 7 and Windows 10 native implementations of the UI is why one breaks and the other doesn't.

To see if this is indeed the cause, try changing the line `Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;` to `Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g.create();` which will make a clone of the Graphics object and leave the original unchanged.

**Edit to clarify the correct answer:**
The issue was caused by the `at.setToRotation` call clearing the default scaling transform on the graphics context after drawing the black square and before drawing the rotated red square. The recommended solution is to call the `rotate(theta,x,y)` form of the method directly on the `Graphics2D` object which preserves the existing scale transform.

Comment: I originally thought I might want to get the original AffineTransform and put it aside before setting my own on Graphics so that I could set it back to restore it. Sadly that did not help. I shall try your approach and will let you know.

Comment: So created the copy using `(Graphics2D)g.create();` but no change. It looks exactly the same.

Comment: Does your Win10 laptop have a high-DPI display by any chance? If so, it's possible that the `at.setToRotation` call is clearing the initial scaling transform on the graphics context resulting in this strange behaviour. In any case, it's better practice to do `g2.rotate(Math.toRadians(45),centerX, centerY)` instead of directly manipulating the AffineTransform.

Comment: You seem to be absolutely correct! I did have my Windows 10 UI scaled to 125% I set it back to 100% to see if it was indeed the cause and it really was. Also I didn't realize `Graphics2D` contained method for rotation. That's why I did it like that. I do wonder if the original approach not working is intended or a bug but anyways I kept the `(Graphics2D)g.create();` part and used the `Graphics2D.rotate` method and it finally works as it should! Thank you very much!